# Цикл повторения раундов в интервальном таймере

Tags: java, android

Идея в том, что два таймера работают последовательно, и повторяется n раз в зависимости от значения numberRound. На деле последовательность срабатывает только 1 раз, а mTextRound показывает значение numberRound+1.
Вот код:

```
public void TimerWorkOut() {
    new CountDownTimer(secWork, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextWork.setText(" " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mTextWork.setText("Rest!");
            TimerRest();
        }
    }.start();
}

public void TimerRest() {
    new CountDownTimer(secRest, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextRest.setText(" " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mTextRest.setText("Just do it!");
        }
    }.start();
}

// Кнопки

public void ClickStart(View view) {
    secWork = pickerSecWork.getValue() * 1000;
    secRest = pickerSecRest.getValue() * 1000;
    numberRound = pickerRound.getValue();
    while (n <= numberRound){
        TimerWorkOut();
        mTextRound.setText("0" + n);
        n = n + 1;
    }
}

// слушатели NumberPicker, и передача данных в TextWiew

NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener onValueChangedWork = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        if (!mIsRunning) {
            mTextWork.setText(intToTime(newVal));
            mCurrentPeriod = newVal;
        }
    }
};

NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener onValueChangedRest = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        if (!mIsRunning) {
            mTextRest.setText(intToTime(newVal));
            mCurrentPeriod = newVal;
        }
    }
};

private String intToTime(int i) {
    return (new SimpleDateFormat("ss")).format(new Date(i * 1000));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот способ решения: счетчик раундов перенесен в метод onFinish TimerRest. Выглядит это так:

```
 public void TimerRest() {
    new CountDownTimer(secRest, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextRest.setText(" " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mTextRest.setText("Just do it!");
            if(n < numberRound) {
                TimerWorkOut();
                n++;
            }
            mTextRound.setText("№" + n);
        }
    }.start();
}

// Кнопки
public void ClickStart(View view) {
    secWork = pickerSecWork.getValue() * 1000;
    secRest = pickerSecRest.getValue() * 1000;
    numberRound = pickerRound.getValue();
    TimerWorkOut();
    mTextRound.setText("№" + n);
}
```